# InfluxBD timestamp from data now

Tags: python, timestamp, influxdb

How to properly convert the current date for example in python timestamp in influxdb? what is the correct formula to do this. I have tried many solutions and I still get the result that timestamp is for example 1970-01-01T00:00:00.15436224Z.